# HTTP Status 408 error during login to the webapp using FORM Authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I have a Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 web application that has a login page. I use FORM authentication to login to the system. I receive the error following:

> HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been
>   exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and
>   re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser

I researched online and couldn't find good enough information.

Here is my web.xml file.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MainMenu</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>customer</role-name>
        <role-name>developer</role-name>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>  
     <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Secure/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/Secure/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

And my tomcat-users.xml file is below:

```
 <tomcat-users>      
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="role1"/>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
 <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
 <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Steps to reproduce? You'll need to include timings.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I can't go further from this step. Whatever I tried, I am displayed the message.